# Why is the file returned with the value in powershell?

Tags: powershell, openssl, return, pfx

I have a 2 powershell files. One invokes `createInstallSSLCertificates.ps1` which will create SSL keys, certificates, etc. At the end, after installing the private CA and public pfx certificate, it returns the thumbprint of the public certificate.

```
$rootobj = Import-Certificate -FilePath $rootcert -CertStoreLocation "cert:\$certuser\Root"
$personalobj = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $serverpfx -CertStoreLocation "cert:\$certuser\My" -Password $pfxexportpassword
if ($personalobj -and $rootobj) {
    Write-Host "Root Thumbprint: $($rootobj.Thumbprint)`n Personal Thumbprint: $($personalobj.Thumbprint)"
    return $personalobj.Thumbprint.ToString()
        } else {
    ...
}
```

The issue comes when looking at the return type on the calling script:

```
 $personalCertThumbprint = &$install_certs_path -InstallCerts $true -user "LocalMachine"
```

The value returned from the `$install_certs_path` is:
`> $personalCertThumbprint = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\installer-and-scripts\CAcerts_certs_0496 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\installer-and-scripts\CAcerts_certs_0496\CAcerts_server_ext.ext EC0D88A1C9D558B6E5DF5165B43938F7BC84E6B7`

and not what i expect:
`> $personalCertThumbprint = EC0D88A1C9D558B6E5DF5165B43938F7BC84E6B7`

I can't figure out why folder and .ext file paths are returned from the file. I've made sure that $personalobj.Thumbprint is just the thumbprint and not a strange string with paths. Is there some implicit value returning happening with powershell?

EDIT: showing the show code for the certificate creating script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="After creation of the certificates, should they be installed.")]
    [bool]
    $InstallCerts=$false,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="If the program should pause after creating the EXT file. This allows for more DNS names to be specified in the certificate")]
    [bool]
    $PauseOnExtFile=$false,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="The SAN, DNS, or Hostname of the server that the personal certificate will be installed on")]
    [string]
    $SAN=$(hostname),

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="The common / friendly name of the personal signed certificate")]
    [string]
    $PersonalCommonName=$(hostname),

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="The common/ friendly name of the CA root certificate")]
    [string]
    $RootCommonName="COMPANY123",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="(LocalMachine | CurrentUser)")]
    [string]
    $user="LocalMachine"
)

if (!($user.Contains("LocalMachine")) -and !($user.Contains("CurrentUser"))) {
    Write-Host "`$user must be either LocalMachine or CurrentUser, not '$user'"
    Exit
}

################## Variables #######################
# change these as you necessary
$base = "CAcerts"
$certuser = $user
$rootpassword = "password"
$pfxexportpassword = "password"
$country = "CH"
$state = "BIOBIO"
$city = "Concepcion"
$org = "mycompany"
$unit = "UNIT"

################ Making filepaths into variables and directory ##################3

# adding random number onto the directory name 
$epochseconds = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochseconds = $epochseconds.Replace(".", "")
$ran = $epochseconds.Substring($epochseconds.Length-4, 4)

$cwd = Get-Location
$dirname = join-path -Path $cwd -ChildPath "$($base)_certs_$($ran)"
$rootkey= $base + "_root_key.key"
$rootpem= $base + "_root_pem.pem"
$rootcert= $base + "_root_ca.crt"
$serverkey= $base + "_server_key.key"
$servercsr= $base + "_server_csr.csr"
$servercert= $base + "_server_cert.crt"
$serverpfx= $base + "_server_pfx.pfx"
$ext_file= $base + "_server_ext.ext"

$rootkey= join-path $dirname $rootkey
$rootpem= join-path $dirname $rootpem
$rootcert= join-path $dirname $rootcert
$serverkey= join-path $dirname $serverkey
$servercsr= join-path $dirname $servercsr
$servercert= join-path $dirname $servercert
$serverpfx= join-path $dirname $serverpfx
$ext_file= join-path $dirname $ext_file

New-item -ItemType Directory $dirname
New-Item -Path $ext_file -ItemType File

################## Install OPENSSL #######################
if (!(Get-Command openssl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    Write-Host "openssl is not a recognized powershell command. Looking to install openssl from chocolatey." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    # install choco
    if (!(Get-Command choco -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; 
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; 
        Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

        # reset env variables to prevent having to reopen shell
        $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
    }

    # install openssl
    if (!(Get-Command openssl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        choco install openssl.light -y
        $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
    }
}
################## CREATE CERTS #######################

# Make private root key
Write-Host "Creating root key"
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:$rootpassword -out $rootkey 2048 
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $rootkey -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$rootkey was not created")
}

# make root certificate CA
Write-Host "Creating root cert CA"
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $rootkey -sha256 -days 3650 -out $rootcert -passin pass:$rootpassword -subj "/C=$country/ST=$state/L=$city/O=$org/OU=$unit/CN=$RootCommonName"
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $rootcert -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$rootcert was not created")
}

# make a PEM privacy enhanced mail key
Write-Host "Creating root PEM"
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $rootkey -sha512 -days 3650 -out $rootpem -passin pass:$rootpassword -subj "/C=$country/ST=$state/L=$city/O=$org/OU=$unit/CN=$RootCommonName"
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $rootpem -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$rootpem was not created")
}

# make server private key
Write-Host "Creating server private key"
openssl genrsa -out $serverkey 2048
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $serverkey -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$serverkey was not created")
}

# create ext file
Write-Host "Creating Ext file"
$content = 
"authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer 
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = $SAN"

$content | Out-File -FilePath $ext_file -Encoding utf8
if ($pauseOnExtFile) {
    write-Host "Pausing execution so you can manually change the EXT file: '$ext_file'
    Add additional DNS names if desired.
    $_pause = Read-Host "Hit enter when ready to continue."
}


# create server .csr file
Write-Host "Creating Server CSR"
openssl req -new -key $serverkey -out $servercsr -subj "/C=$country/ST=$state/L=$city/O=$org/OU=$unit/CN=$PersonalCommonName"
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $servercsr -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$servercsr was not created")
}

# server cert
Write-Host "Creating Server CERT"
openssl x509 -req -in $servercsr -CA $rootpem -CAkey $rootkey -CAcreateserial -out $servercert -days 3650 -sha512 -extfile $ext_file -extensions 'req_ext' -passin pass:$rootpassword
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $servercert -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$servercert was not created")
}

# convert crt to pfx formatting
Write-Host "Converting CERT to PFX"
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey $serverkey -in $servercert -passout pass:$pfxexportpassword -name $base -out $serverpfx
if ( !(Test-Path -Path $serverpfx -PathType Leaf)) {
    Write-Host("$serverpfx was not created")
}

################## INSTALL CERTS #######################
if ($InstallCerts) {
$pfxexportpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pfxexportpassword -Force -AsPlainText
    try {
        $rootobj = Import-Certificate -FilePath $rootcert -CertStoreLocation "cert:\$certuser\Root"
        $personalobj = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $serverpfx -CertStoreLocation "cert:\$certuser\My" -Password $pfxexportpassword
        Write-Host "Root Certificate installed in $certuser\Trust Root CA as $RootCommonName"
        Write-Host "Server Certificate installed in $certuser\Personal as $PersonalCommonName. Thumbprint: ${personalobj.Thumbprint}"
        Write-Host "Program was successful creating certs $base."
        Write-Host "Exiting ...."

        if ($personalobj -and $rootobj) {
            Write-Host "Root Thumbprint: $($rootobj.Thumbprint)`n Personal Thumbprint: $($personalobj.Thumbprint)"
            return $personalobj.Thumbprint
        } else {
            return "Error installing the certificates"
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Installation failed. of certificates. Check permissions and try again."
        Exit
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with ```$personalobj.Thumbprint```, btw. you do not need to call the method ```ToString()```, it is already a string. Guess we need to see the whole scriptcode, most probably you output those paths earlier....

Comment: I added the whole file for better context

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent through the pipeline or to a file) is _implicitly output_ from a script or function. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects). 
See the linked duplicate for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you invoke a script you must take care what it outputs on which streams, e.g.:

```
New-item -ItemType Directory $dirname
New-Item -Path $ext_file -ItemType File
```

The output of those two commands will also be part of the information stored in the variable `$personalCertThumbprint`.

To avoid that do:

```
$null = New-item -ItemType Directory $dirname
$null = New-Item -Path $ext_file -ItemType File
```

Btw. in case of your parameter specification take a look at [SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2):

```
[bool]$InstallCerts -> [switch]$InstallCerts
```

[switch] is by default FALSE and once specified it becomes TRUE or you can specify it explicitly `-InstallCerts:$true`.